# Applying transitions to preloaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Images-rotation](https://github.com/sladex/images-rotation) in order to create a slideshow that plays when hovering over an image. I'd like to add transitions between the images, such as jQuery's fadeIn. The images are preloaded, which is why I think what I've attempted so far hasn't been successful.

I've also created this (http://jsfiddle.net/Lydmn2xn/) to hopefully easily show what's being used, although all of the code is found in the Javascript plugin itself. So far I've tried adding variations of the line $this.fadeIn("slow"); in various spots with no luck. Below is the code for the Javascript plugin with changes I've tried to make. Not sure how to point them out as I can't bold the text in the code. (Note: said changes are not in the Jfiddle, as they don't produce any changes).

```
$.fn.imagesRotation = function (options) {
var defaults = {
        images: [],         // urls to images
        dataAttr: 'images', // html5 data- attribute which contains an array with urls to images
        imgSelector: 'img', // element to change
        interval: 1500,     // ms
        intervalFirst: 1500, // first image change, ms
        callback: null      // first argument would be the current image url
    },
    settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

var clearRotationInterval = function ($el) {
        clearInterval($el.data('imagesRotaionTimeout'));
        $el.removeData('imagesRotaionTimeout');
        clearInterval($el.data('imagesRotaionInterval'));
        $el.removeData('imagesRotaionInterval');
    },
    getImagesArray = function ($this) {
        var images = settings.images.length ? settings.images : $this.data(settings.dataAttr);
        return $.isArray(images) ? images : false;
    },
    preload = function (arr) {  // images preloader
        $(arr).each(function () {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
$this.fadeIn("slow");
        });
    },
    init = function () {
        var imagesToPreload = [];
        this.each(function () {  // preload next image
            var images = getImagesArray($(this));
            if (images && images.length > 1) {
                imagesToPreload.push(images[1]);
            }
        });
        preload(imagesToPreload);
    };

init.call(this);

this.on('mouseenter.imagesRotation', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $img = settings.imgSelector ? $(settings.imgSelector, $this) : null,
        images = getImagesArray($this),
        imagesLength = images ? images.length : null,
        changeImg = function () {
            var prevIndex = $this.data('imagesRotationIndex') || 0,
                index = (prevIndex + 1 < imagesLength) ? prevIndex + 1 : 0,
                nextIndex = (index + 1 < imagesLength) ? index + 1 : 0;
            $this.data('imagesRotationIndex', index);
            if ($img && $img.length > 0) {
                if ($img.is('img')) {
                    $img.attr('src', images[index]);
                    $this.fadeIn('slow');
                }
                else {
                    $img.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
                    $img.fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }
            if (settings.callback) {
                settings.callback(images[index]);
            }
            preload([images[nextIndex]]); // preload next image
        };
    if (imagesLength) {
        clearRotationInterval($this); // in case of dummy intervals
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            changeImg();
            var interval = setInterval(changeImg, settings.interval);
            $this.data('imagesRotaionInterval', interval); // store to clear interval on mouseleave
        }, settings.intervalFirst);
        $this.data('imagesRotaionTimeout', timeout);
    }
}).on('mouseleave.imagesRotation', function () {
    clearRotationInterval($(this));
}).on('imagesRotationRemove', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.off('.imagesRotation');
    clearRotationInterval($this);
});
};

$.fn.imagesRotationRemove = function () {
this.trigger('imagesRotationRemove');
};
```

Would that do the trick if it was in the right spot, or does fadeIn/Out not apply to preloaded images? Any help or tips are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The `.imagesRotation()` code doesn't do a fade.  Unless it has such a feature that you can specify with an option, you will have to change the actual `.imagesRotation()` code to get a fade (not something you can add outside that code).  What exact code have you tried so far?  FYI, I don't think your issue has anything to do with preload.

Comment: I've tried modifying the .js file for Images-Rotation by adding $this.fadeIn("slow"); (or similar things) in several spots hoping that at the moment in time that it loads the image it would do so in addition to fading it in, which it hasn't so far. I should add I am very new to Javascript.

Comment: The way this site works is you have to post (in your question) the relevant code and THEN people will help you figure out how to change it to achieve your goal.  No code and you will rarely get a good answer.  Include the relevant code and you will often get a good answer.  Do not expect us to go try to guess what the relevant code is in some offsite resource.  That is not the way this site works for a variety of reasons.

Comment: FYI, you can only fadeOut one image and fadeIn another image at the same time (e.g. a cross fade) with Javascript when you actually have two separate images that you are fading between.  You can't do that with just one image which is likely the issue with your code.  If you have a newly loaded image that you want to fadeIn, the image has to initially be not visible (e.g. opacity `0`) so it can fadeIn FROM that state.  If it's already visible, then jQuery's `fadeIn()` has nothing to do.

Comment: That makes sense, which is sort of what I expected without being able to explain it as clearly as you have. Thanks. (Although I am attempting to fade between two images, as the page is full of slideshows that go through several images). I'll try and edit my original question as well.

Comment: The issue is that `.imagesRotation()` doesn't have multiple images.  It just changes the `.src` of one image to the next URL.  You can't do a cross fade from one image to the next that way.